# JSON data posts from Angular 2 front end to Asp.Net Core web api - loses values

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I am sending values from an Angular 2 front end as visible here:

```
  censusManagementSearch(search: any): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token') });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let body = JSON.stringify({ practice: search.practice, location: search.location, name: search.name });
    return this.http.post(this._api.apiUrl + 'censusmanagement', body, options)
      .map((response: Response) => {
        return response;
    })
      .catch((err: any) => {
        return Observable.throw(err.json().error || 'Server error');
    });
  }
```

Everything there is working fine.  It's going to a C# back end as seen below.  If it matters it's an ASP.Net core web api

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PostCensusManagement([FromBody] int practice, int location, string name)
```

When I put a break point on this the values are 0 for the ints and "" for the string.  I've tried taking `[FromBody]` out as well as replacing it with other options.  Each time the values are blank.

Here is an image showing the values being sent in Chrome
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.  I'll leave it here in case anyone else runs into this issue.  In order for the web api to see the data I had to create a class for it.

```
public class CensusSearch
{
    public int location { get; set; }
    public int practice { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

And changed the controller to this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult PostCensusManagement([FromBody] CensusSearch search)
```

Comment: also add changes in your ng service method as 'Observable<any>' to Observable<CensusSearch> and you can change body with CensusSearch object with stringify